# The order of transformed-matrix multiplication in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, transform

Here I have a point P(x,y,z,1). Then I rotated the P around a known angel and a vector to point P1(x1,y1,z1,1). And according to P1's coordinates, I can translate P1 to point P2 (0,0,z1,1). Now I want to get only one matrix that can transform P to P2 directly So, my code is below:

```
GLfloat P[4] ={5,-0.6,3.8,1};
GLfloat m[16];  //This is the rotation matrix to calculate P1 from P
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(theta, v1,v2,v3);//theta and (v1,v2,v3) is constant
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
glPopMatrix();

//calculate P1 from P and matrix m
GLfloat P1;
P1[0] = P[0]*m[0]+P[1]*m[4]+P[2]*m[8]+m[12];
P1[1] = P[0]*m[1]+P[1]*m[5]+P[2]*m[9]+m[13];
P1[2] = P[0]*m[2]+P[1]*m[6]+P[2]*m[10]+m[14];
P1[3] = P[0]*m[3]+P[1]*m[7]+P[2]*m[11]+m[15];
//after calculation P1 = {0.15,-3.51,-5.24,1}

GLfloat m1[16]; //P multiply m1 can get P2 directly
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(theta, v1,v2,v3);//theta and (v1,v2,v3) is constant as above
glTranslatef(-P1[0], -P1[1], 0);// after rotation we get P1, then translation to P2  
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m1);
glPopMatrix();

//calculate P2 from P and matrix m1
GLfloat P2[4];
P2[0] = P[0]*m1[0]+P[1]*m1[4]+P[2]*m1[8]+m1[12];
P2[1] = P[0]*m1[1]+P[1]*m1[5]+P[2]*m1[9]+m1[13];
P2[2] = P[0]*m1[2]+P[1]*m1[6]+P[2]*m1[10]+m1[14];
P2[3] = P[0]*m1[3]+P[1]*m1[7]+P[2]*m1[11]+m1[15];
//after this calculation, I expect P2 should be (0,0,-5.24) that is (0,0,p1[2])
//however, the real result is not my expectation! Where I do wrong???
```

Actually, I analyzed this problem. I found the order of matrix multiplication is weird. 
After I do  glRotatef(theta, v1,v2,v3), I get the matrix m. That's OK.
m is

m[0]  m[1]  m[2]  0

m[4]  m[5]  m[6]  0

m[8]  m[9]  m[10] 0

0     0     0     1

And if I do glTranslatef(-P1[0], -P1[1], 0) alone, I get the translation matrix m'.
m' is

1      0      0  0

0      1      0  0

0      0      0  1

-P1[0] -P1[1] 0  1

So I think after do glRotatef(theta, v1,v2,v3) and glTranslatef(-P1[0], -P1[1], 0), 
the m1 = m*m', that is

m[0]    m[1]    m[2]  0

m[4]    m[5]    m[6]  0

m[8]    m[9]    m[10] 0

-P1[0]  -P2[0]  0     1

However, in the actual program, m1 = m'*m, so the P2 is not my expected result!

I know doing the translate first and then doing the rotation that can get my right result, but why I cannot do the rotation first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotation and translation are not commutable. (Matrix multiplication in general is not commutable, but in some special cases, such as all translations, all **2D** rotations, all scalings, **one** rotation mixed with **uniform** scalings, the actions/matrices are commutable).

If you rotate first, then the translation will be in the direction of the rotated coordinate.

As an example, translate by (1, 0), then rotate by 90 degree, will give the origin at (1, 0), (assuming starting from identity matrix). As opposed to rotate by 90 degree first, will give the origin at (0, 1).

On the mathematical side, since this is coordinate transformation, any new transformation will be left multiply to the current coordinate transformation matrix. e.g. If T is matrix of a new transformation action, C is the current transformation matrix, then after the transformation, the current transformation matrix will become TC.

Comment: Even rotations don't commute with each other.

Comment: @ChristianRau: You are correct. Rotation is commutative only in 2D, it is not commutative in higher order: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Thank you very much, I've already figured out what confused me!